# CSRF Tag Still Rejecting Twilio Requests

Tags: python, django, post, twilio, csrf

I'm writing a simple view which takes in a Twilio SMS request and returns a simple SMS, based on this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2014/04/building-a-simple-sms-message-application-with-twilio-and-django-2.html).

For some reason, requests still are met with 403 Forbidden:

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /haul/response
[20/Jul/2017 17:39:42] "POST /haul/response HTTP/1.1" 403 2857`
```

My view is as follows:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from twilio.rest import Client
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def response(request):
    twiml = '<Response><Message>Test</Message></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(twiml, content_type='text/xml')
```

I know this isn't a server issue since I experience the same results on both my production server and local machine. The strangest part is that at one time, I had this working. It's almost as if the `@csrf_exempt` decorator isn't working.

Comment: Silly question, but have you restarted the server after making that change?

Comment: @philnash by restart the server do you mean the Django host (manage.py runserver) or the actual _server_? It's hosted on a Digital Ocean droplet. I can try.

Comment: @philnash No luck restarting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just resolved this. For anyone who's interested, the issue was the my urls.py was pointing to the wrong endpoint, so requests were being rejected. I altered this during some testing and forgot to change it back. Cost me quite a few hours. Devil's in the details!